# can't import pkg_sources under python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was trying to command `sudo xattr -rd com.apple.quanrantine` in order to pass apple's quanrantine and it reported `No module named pkg_resources`

Then I checked if my pkg_resources have got wrong. Then I tried import pkg_sources in python3, it worked.

However, python2.7, which is my default version, reported `No module named pkg_resources` when i apply same command

how i can solve this

Comment: `pkg_resources` isn't in Python 2.7's standard library, so it is unclear why would you expect it to be available? Is it something you downloaded and installed?

Comment: i was trying to command `sudo xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine ` and it reported "no module named pkg_resources".